# Как вывести строку в обратном порядке с помощью awk?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, строки, bash, awk

Как вывести строку в обратном порядке с помощью awk?

Comment: Определите «в обратном порядке».  По байтам?  По символам?  По словам?

Comment: каков вопрос, таков и [ответ](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/05/different-ways-to-reverse-string-in.html)

Answer (score 3):

Why awk? Just rev!

```
echo 12345|rev
```

Если прям нужен awk, то:

```
echo 12345 | awk '{for (i = length($0); i > 0; i--) {printf("%s", substr($0, i, 1));} print "";}'
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461625/reverse-the-order-of-characters-in-a-string/11461628)